# Python. Call function for each item from a list

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

So, I have this:

a list:

```
my_list = ['Spike', 'Alex', 'Andrei']
```

and I'm calling a function:

```
ThisIsAExample(name= )
```

Now here I have two problems:

1: `my_list` is a list taken from a database and there will be more items added to it by a user

2: `ThisIsAExample` can take only item as `name=`.

Is there a way to call a function multiple types when a new item is added to the list without me having to add ThisIsAExample(name=Spike) everytime a item is added to the list?

EDIT:

My code is the following:

```
results = [InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=uuid4(),
            title=my_list,
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                some_content,disable_web_page_preview=True,
                parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN))]
```

It's from the python-telegram-group library. here the `name` is 'title'. And I need to use the each item from my list in `title=`. and I need it to do it so every time I have a new item in the list it will generate and repeat the function again under the previous one that is the same thing but with different 'title='

Comment: Share the code for thisisAExamle plz..My friend, not sure what you asking...and what is the item inside name=....

Comment: You should implement observer pattern for track changes on your list and trigger observers.

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus i've updated my question :)